# Trimming whitespace in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trim

I have tried using the TRIM() in MySQL to delete all of the whitespace in every field in a column but it will only remove it from the front. I have long strings that have spaces in the middle next to hyphens and I need the space between the hyphens removed. Is there a way to do this?

```
UPDATE FOO set FIELD2 = TRIM(FIELD2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`REPLACE()` method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), which can replace every occurrence of a character by another:

```
UPDATE foo SET field2 = REPLACE(field2, ' ', '');
```

This query will remove every spaces in the `field2` column.

Definition of the method, from the MySQL doc:

> Returns the string *str* with all occurrences of the string *from_str* replaced by the string *to_str*. `REPLACE()` performs a case-sensitive match when searching for *from_str*.
>
> mysql> SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
>           -> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'
>
> This function is multi-byte safe.